# Getting error with Export Power BI api call

Tags: powerbi, report

I am trying to upload report on my pbi workspace using axios in node.js

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('', fs.createReadStream(oneStepBack + 'report.pbix'), {
  filename: 'report.pbix',
});

// Make the Axios request
axios.post(url, formData, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authToken
  },
})
  .then(response => {
    // Handle the response
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Handle errors
    console.error(error);
  });
```

But this code is giving me error

> error:
> {code: 'InvalidFileSizeError', pbi.error: {…}}

However the same pbix report I am able to upload using Postman.